# How to find given bitmap image is blurred image or unblurred image in android

Tags: android, image, opencv, bitmap, blur

In my android application i need to find given/camera capturing image is blurred or not.
i using following code from help of openCV library. but it will not give always correct result.
please help me, thanks in advance.

```
private boolean isBlurredImage(Bitmap image) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inDither = true;
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    int l = CvType.CV_8UC1;
    Mat matImage = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, matImage);
    Mat matImageGrey = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(matImage, matImageGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat dst2 = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, dst2);

    Mat laplacianImage = new Mat();
    dst2.convertTo(laplacianImage, l);
    Imgproc.Laplacian(matImageGrey, laplacianImage, CvType.CV_8U);
    Mat laplacianImage8bit = new Mat();
    laplacianImage.convertTo(laplacianImage8bit, l);
    System.gc();

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(laplacianImage8bit.cols(),
            laplacianImage8bit.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(laplacianImage8bit, bmp);

    int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getHeight() * bmp.getWidth()];
    bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight());
    if (bmp != null)
        if (!bmp.isRecycled()) {
            bmp.recycle();

        }
    int maxLap = -16777216;

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {

        if (pixels[i] > maxLap) {
            maxLap = pixels[i];
        }
    }
    int soglia = -6118750;

    if (maxLap < soglia || maxLap == soglia) {
        Log.i(MIOTAG, "--------->blur image<------------");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.i(MIOTAG, "----------->Not blur image<------------");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can detect by using openCV java color detection ...

Comment: @VenuNalla , here i need only given image(color or back&white) is blurred or not.

Comment: your question is not meaning full please elborate me...

Comment: @VenuNalla , when user capturing the image from camera. i need to find that image is blurred or not.

Comment: I think you'll get better results if you'll use signed type (or may be better use real type) instead of unsigned char because Laplacian gives you positive and negative values, not only positive. And use Laplcaian absolute value for comparsion with threshold.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-14.pdf) is one of the best articles regarding Out Of Focus images I've read. It's made by HP researchers and it's implemented in some of their cameras. It basically splits the image into small squares (as in a grid) and computes the blur factor for every region. After that, based on a decision tree it makes the final decision (blurry image or not).

I hope this will help you accomplish your work.

Best regards!

Comment: Hi guys i want to get image is blur or not. please help me.i am implementing above code but it is crash..06-04 11:38:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 11:38:05.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4704): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: n_Mat